# How to change permission for writing in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am running WordPress on my computer (localhost). I am unable to load plugins, pictures etc.. Is it possible to change the permission for writing in a easy way?

I know this is a beginner question but i really need help..

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: What do you mean by "permission for writing"?